Sort x axis of plotly express stacked bar chart by total for the bar
I have created a stacked bar chart in using plotly express that visualises edits made to a files in GDrive, and who made those edits.
My source dataframe has columns

file_path
emailAddress (of the person editing the file)
tally

I have file_path plotted on the x axis.

The problem I'm having is that I want all the bars to appear in descending order of edits, regardless of who made those edits. As you can see that's not happening right now.
Here is my code:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

# Get a list of unique email addresses to create one trace per email address
email_addresses = df['emailAddress'].unique()

# Create a trace for each email address
for email in email_addresses:
    df_filtered = df[df['emailAddress'] == email]
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_filtered['path_name'], y=df_filtered['tally'], name=email))

# Update the layout to stack the bars
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', xaxis_title="File path", yaxis_title="Tally", title="Tally by file path and Email Address")

fig.show()

Can anyone suggest how I change this to get all bars appearing in descending order of edits, regardless of who made the edits.

You need to specify the xaxis categoryorder.

Set categoryorder to "total ascending" or "total descending" if
order should be determined by the numerical order of the values.

fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='total descending')

See Bar Chart with Sorted or Ordered Categories.
